# How to use a PHP file to control the content of a blog post

Tags: php, posts, blog, blog-page

Let's say I've created a page with the ID `62`. If I then create a PHP file named `page-62.php`, I could edit my page from there. I want to do the same with a blog post. How would that be possible?

Comment: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/03/post-type-templates-in-4-7/

Comment: Thank you , but I know templates, this is not what I was searching for.

Comment: OK - I'm not sure what you're asking for then. `page-62` is a custom template for the page with ID 62. AFAIK there's no equivalent mechanism for posts ([hierarchy diagram](https://wphierarchy.com/)) except by using custom templates. But at first glance it looks to me like that does what you're asking for, doesn't it? What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: I think Rup is on the right track.  Just assign "post-##" to this post template and it works great